# Where does the logger command send information if there is no logging daemon installed

Tags: docker, syslog

Inside a Docker container which doesn't have rsyslogd installed, what happens to logs from the command `logger error "my error message"`?

It seems odd to have the `logger` command available, without anything to capture and process the log events it emits. I would naively have expected, both the logger command and the mechanism to process the log messages to be packaged together, it doesn't make sense to me to have one without the other.

============= EDIT with more information =============

I'm using the Dockers official MariaDB 10.1 image. I'm entering the container with the command

```
docker exec -it maria_10_2_test bash
```

then I'm using the Linux `logger` utility to try and log to the syslog like with

```
logger error "My message here"
```

The `logger` command exits successfully with a 0 code, but nothing is written to the syslog (as there is no syslog daemon in the image).

I think this question is more general than Docker and is a general Linux question. If on the host machine (Ubuntu 20.04), I turn off the syslog service and socket, I can still use the logger command, it still gives a zero exit code and nothing is written to the syslog.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  Which image are you using, and what application code is trying to call this `logger` tool?

Comment: @DavidMaze I've updated my question with the information you requested.